# Notepad++ merging different lines with duplicate words

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, merge, notepad

I have some tough work to do let me explain as best as i can. Merge the duplicate words on different lines.

Example:

i like 33 big black cars122

cars122 notfree

The result i want:

i like 33 big black cars122 cars122 notfree

there is like 200k lines and some don't even have duplicate words, i want only duplicates to merge. I've been thinking about it for a week now and my brain is not powerful enough to come with solution

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1411586/edit) and add more examples and expected result. Are duplicate **ALLWAYS** separated with a single newline? Could there be some other words in between or not? What should be the result for `abc def\nabc def hij\nxyz abc`? ...

Answer (score 1):

If you literally want to replace cars122 repeated then here you go:
[image: Extended Example]

If you want to do something more complicated with all repeated words you would need to use the Regular Expression option and I would have to see the file to test before I would be comfortable suggesting a solution.

This would be much tougher on the non-repeating words. Regardless of your approach (and there are many) You basically need some angle that you can make rules that cover all your cases.